# Stable graph of stable curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

Let $\Gamma = (\mathbf{V},\mathbf{H}, \mathbf{L},g, v,i,\ell)$ be a stable graph.
Let $(\mathcal{C},p_1,\cdots,p_n)$ be a stable curve with the dual curve $\Gamma$ and let $(\tilde{\mathcal{C}}_v,(q_h)_{h\in \mathbf{H}(v)})_{v\in \mathbf{V}(\Gamma)}$ be the components of the normalization of $\mathcal{C}.$ There exist an exact sequence of group

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \longrightarrow & \prod_{v\in \mathbf{V}(\Gamma)} Aut(\tilde{\mathcal{C}}_v,(q_h)_{h\in\mathbf{H}(v)})& \longrightarrow Aut(\mathcal{C},p_1,\cdots,p_n) & \longrightarrow &Aut(\Gamma) \longrightarrow & 0
\end{array}
$$

I need to show the sequence is exact and my problem is that if I take $(\tilde{ \sigma}_{v})_{v\in \mathbf{V}(\Gamma)} \in \prod_{v\in \mathbf{V}(\Gamma)} Aut(\tilde{\mathcal{C}}_v,(q_h)_{h\in \mathbf{H}(v)}$ how to send it to $\sigma \in Aut(\mathcal{C},p_1,\cdots,p_n)$ such that it has to be stable.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? The first map is just saying that some of the automorphisms of a stable pointed curve come from automorphisms of its individual components.

Comment: Yeah that's the point, I'm trying to find out how to send the $(\sigma_v)_{v\in\mathbf{V}(\Gamma)}$ to a $\sigma\in Aut (\mathcal{C},p_1,\cdots, p_n))$. And for the second map I'm looking a way to define a bijective map $\mathbf{V}(\Gamma)\longrightarrow\mathbf{V}(\Gamma)$, $\mathbf{H}(\Gamma)\longrightarrow\mathbf{H}(\Gamma)$ in order to obtain an automorphism $\phi: \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$ fixing the $p_i$ thus i can define $Aut(\mathcal{C},p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_n) \longrightarrow Aut(\Gamma).$

Comment: It's hard to make sense of the notation without anything being specified, but there should be a condition saying marked points on the normalization (so marked points on the stable curve + points lying over nodes) are fixed by the $\sigma_v$. This means that 1) you can descend a compatible collection of $\sigma_v$ back down from the normalization to the stable curve, and 2) that this descended automorphism preserves not just the stable curve, but the pointed stable curve.

Comment: Thank you so much Tabes Bridges. With your hint I found a way to define all the maps in the sequence .